# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects while using pymysql.cursors

Tags: mysql, python

I work on python. I have a query where I have 3 tables on my db.

1. I have connected to a db and from a mysql table pulled out all the rows from two columns (idnum,clientname) e.g. (1234,renolds), (1235,renolds2)
2. Then each idnum has a seperate table e.g. sample_divya_1234;sample_divya_1235, from each of these tables we need to take all emails and lnames. (Note: each idnum has many email and lname records)
3. All the clientnames taken in step 1 are present in another table sample_divya3, so for each clientname need to pull out fname e.g.(saha, renolds)
4. Now email,lname,fname must all get dropped into a new table sql_table1

#### Input Tables

```
Sample_divya1:

    +-----+------------+---
    | idnum | clientname | 
    +-------+------------+-
    | 1234  | renold    | 
    | 1235  | renold1    | 
   +-------+------------+

sample_divya_1234:

   +-------------------+----------+
    | email             | lname    |
    +-------------------+----------+
    | abc@yahoo.com     | abcd     |
    | bcd@gmail.com     | bcda     |
    +-------------------+----------+
    **sample_divya_1235**
    +------------------+-----------+
    | email            | lname     |
    +------------------+-----------+
    | xyz@gmail.com    | xyza      |
    | nag@gmail.com    | sai       |
    | hij@gmail.com    | klm       |
    +------------------+-----------+

    sample_divya3:

    +--------+------------+
    | fname  | clientname |
    +--------+------------+
    | saha   | renold     |
    | hasini | renold1      |
    +--------+------------+
```

PRG:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from time import time
import datetime

conn=pymysql.connect(CONNECTDETAILS)
query = "select idnum from sample_divya1"
cursor=conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
data = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("drop table if exists sql_table1")
sql_table = "create table sql_table1(email varchar(128),lname varchar(128),fname varchar(128))"
cursor.execute(sql_table)


for id in data:
    cursor.execute("select A.idnum, B.fname, B.clientname,C.lname,C.email from (select idnum,clientname from sample_divya1)A cross join (select fname,clientname  from sample_divya3 )B where A.clientname=B.clientname cross join (select email, lname from sample_divya_"+id[0]+")C where A.idnum =id")
    data_1=cursor.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    print data_1
    cursor.executemany("insert into sql_table1 (email,lname,fname) values (?,?,?)",data_1)
    conn.commit()
conn.commit()
```

#### Output required:

```
+------------------+----------+--------+
| email            | lname    | fname  |
+------------------+----------+--------+
| abc@yahoo.com    | abcd     | saha   |
| bcd@gmail.com    | bcda     | saha   |
| xyz@gmail.com    | xyza     | hasini |
| nag@gmail.com    | sai      | hasini |
| hij@gmail.com    | klm      | hasini |
```

Mistake is in my highlighted part of my query

"""    # cursor.execute("select  B.fname,C.lname,C.email from (select idnum,clientname from sample_divya1)A cross join (select fname,clientname  from sample_divya3 )B where A.clientname=B.clientname cross join (select email, lname from sample_divya_"+id[0]+")C  ***where A.idnum = id"***)"""

Here on trail and got to know that ""Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause""
so can someone help in this where clause

Comment: I'd recommend to create stored procedure which accepts source parameters and returns whole outpuut you need.

Answer (score 1):

It's the string concatenation on the line after `for id in data:`. `id` is an array (which is the row returned by `select idnum from sample_divya1`).

Change your code to read:

```
for id in data:
    cursor.execute("select A.idnum, B.fname, B.clientname,C.lname,C.email from (select idnum,clientname from sample_divya1)A cross join (select fname,clientname  from sample_divya3 )B where A.clientname=B.clientname cross join (select email, lname from sample_divya_"+id[0]+")C where A.idnum =id")
```

Note the `id[0]` instead of `id`. This should now contain the required `idnum` from the query `select idnum from sample_divya1`.

If you have trouble with this, assign the generated query to a variable and print it before executing it. Inspect it with your eyes, then try to run it from the MySQL command line.

Comment: Similarly, you'll need to concatenate `id[0]` for "id" where you have `where A.idnum =id`

Answer (score 0):

Once:

```
CREATE VIEW sample_divya_all
SELECT *, '1234' AS tablenum FROM sample_divya_1234
UNION ALL
SELECT *, '1235' AS tablenum FROM sample_divya_1235;
```

If all partitional tables are `Engine=MyISAM`, may create a table with `Engine=Merge` instead.

The query:

```
SELECT sda.email, sda.lname, sd3.fname
  FROM sample_divya_all sda
  JOIN sample_divya1 sd1 ON sd1.idnum = sda.tablenum
  JOIN sample_divya3 sd3 ON sd3.clientname = sd1.clientname;
```